# Twitter-bootstrap sidebar (span4) goes under main element (span8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sidebar

Im using twitter-bootstrap in my rails app

i was following this tutorial : http://untame.net/2012/08/twitter-bootstrap-build-a-stunning-two-column-blog/

and i have the same `span 8` main element with a `span4` widget sidebar

but for some reasons it looks like this : http://s11.postimage.org/y2cf9wlrn/Bootstrap_Sidebar_fail.png

does anyone know what is going on ? i have tried to increase the container size & lowering the main elements span size but that doesn't help

btw the app is responsive

here is how my layout file looks

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  #navbar removed for clearer code
</div><!-- end of Navbar -->

<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     #carousel removed for clearer code
  </div> <!-- Carousel items -->

<div id="user_nav" float="left">      
 #removed for clearer code
</div><!-- Flash messages-->

<div class="row">   
  <div class="span8">

    <div class="hero-unit">
      <!-- page specific content is loaded here -->
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  </div><!-- end main area -->

  <aside class="span4"><!-- Sidebar starts here  -->    
    <div class="row">

        <div class="widget span4">
           #widget removed
        </div><!-- end widget -->

      </div><!-- end widget row -->
    </aside><!-- end sidebar -->
  </div><!-- end row -->
  #footer removed
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: when we put your code within a fiddle it works as expected -- http://jsfiddle.net/FfSHz/

Comment: yes it does http://jsfiddle.net/FfSHz/ this is without the navbar hedder that is outside the container

Comment: and it works with the nav-bar http://jsfiddle.net/FfSHz/ damn i have no idea what is going on lol

Comment: something else is messing with it within your code, check closing tags, and make sure they're all there and correct.

Comment: You where right, i took a look at my "show" view and it had a couple of leftover closing divs from a copy paste - could you answer the question so i can mark you as the right answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seemed like you had some opened div tags that werent closed.. so checking your source for that would help it as the layout you posted seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your ".span8" and ".span4" elements are inside ".container > .row"?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="span8">...</div>
       <div class="span4">...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i put my layouts skeleton in my post, you can take a look at it :)